# How to use AspectJ to profile lambda functions in Java Play Framework 2.5.x?

Tags: java, playframework, java-8, aspectj, kamon

I have a Java application built using Play 2.5x. I am using AspectJ with Kamon to profile methods in my selected packages, and am reporting the execution details in Jaeger. It works fine with synchronous methods but fails when it comes to reporting asynchronous ones. For example, if I have a thenApply block which is executed after a future completes, then I cannot profile the lambda inside the thenApply in the current scheme of things. I do not want to add any extra code to my Play app and want the aspect to take care of the profiling. Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that we encourage everyone asking questions to provide code, not just to ask general questions. A problem can best be solved if it can be reproduced. So you probably want to edit your question and add more detail, such as code and build/run configuration, ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If it is too much code to quote here, just post the essentials and point to an additional GitHub repo.